# IN JAVA PROGRAMMING

Tags: java, swing

i would like to create a skill program, like in warcraft,,,
my question is : the action listener is wants to final the integer sp ...but when i final the integer sp, it says that cannot change the value of a final integer....

Heres the code and please try to run it:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class Skills
{
 public static void main(String[] args)  
{
    //DECLARATION
    int sp = 0;
    JFrame skillframe = new JFrame("Skills");
    final JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
    final JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
    ImageIcon s1 = new ImageIcon("skill1.jpg");
    ImageIcon s2 = new ImageIcon("skill2.jpg");
    ImageIcon s3 = new ImageIcon("skill3.jpg");
    ImageIcon s4 = new ImageIcon("skill4.jpg");
    ImageIcon s5 = new ImageIcon("stats.gif");
    final JButton skills = new JButton("Skills");
    JButton skill1 = new JButton(s1);
    JButton skill2 = new JButton(s2);
    JButton skill3 = new JButton(s3);
    JButton skill4 = new JButton(s4);
    JButton stats = new JButton(s5);
    final JButton back = new JButton("BacK");
    final JButton levelup = new JButton("Level UP!");
    JLabel points = new JLabel("Skill Points : " + sp );

    ///SETTINGS :
    //   Skills
    panel1.add(skills);
    skills.setBounds(226, 82, 64, 64);
    skills.setBackground(Color.black);
    skills.setForeground(Color.white);
    //   Level UP!
    panel1.add(levelup);
    levelup.setBounds(10, 82, 100, 64);
    levelup.setBackground(Color.black);
    levelup.setForeground(Color.white);
    //   Skill 1
    panel2.add(skill1);
    skill1.setBounds(10, 10, 64, 64);
    //   Skill 2
    panel2.add(skill2);
    skill2.setBounds(82, 10, 64, 64);
    //   Skill 3
    panel2.add(skill3);
    skill3.setBounds(154, 10, 64,64);
    //   Skill 4
    panel2.add(skill4);
    skill4.setBounds(226, 10, 64, 64);
    //   Stats
    panel2.add(stats);
    stats.setBounds(10, 82, 64, 64);
    //   Back
    panel2.add(back);
    back.setBounds(226, 82, 64, 64);
    back.setBackground(Color.black);
    back.setForeground(Color.white);
    //   Points
    panel2.add(points);
    points.setBounds(100, 82, 100, 64);
    points.setForeground(Color.white);
    //   Frame
    skillframe.setSize(310,195);
    panel1.setSize(310,195);
    panel2.setSize(310,195);
    skillframe.add(panel1);
    skillframe.add(panel2);
    panel1.setBackground(Color.black);
    panel2.setBackground(Color.black);
    panel1.setLayout(null);
    panel2.setLayout(null);
    panel2.setVisible(false);
    skillframe.setVisible(true);
    //    ACTIONLISTENER
    skills.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
           panel1.setVisible(false);
           panel2.setVisible(true);
    //....................................................................................................................................................... 
    back.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
           panel1.setVisible(true);
           panel2.setVisible(false); 

        }
    });
    //.......................................................................................................................................................
       }
    });  
    //...........................................................................................................................................................     
    levelup.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
           sp ++;
        }
    });
   //...................................................................................................................................
}
```

}

Comment: you can translate it with google if you dont understand it in english "cannot change the value of a final integer"

Comment: You should make you `sp` variable a class member `private int sp;`. Also, start using `new ...` and split your code into several methods rather than having everything in `main`. Finally, consider using LayoutManager's rather than setting it `null` everywhere.

Comment: You should re-phrase and format your question a little better, and cut the code down to the point.

Comment: mam/ sir.. can you copy my code and run it please ^^.... and give me some solution,,, cause im a begginer ^^ sorry for inconvinience..

Answer (score 2):

A `final` variable is, well, `final`. It means that its value cannot be changed (or, it's reference cannot be changed, in case of an object type) after it has been initialized.

Reference: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4

The reason it doesn't work with `++` is that it is in effect a re-assignment (`sp = sp + 1`)

**Edit**

Also, the reason it doesn't work *not* to declare it final, is that you are using it within an anonymous class. To be able to use it in an anonymous class, it has to be declared `final`, because the compiler needs to be sure that the reference is in fact the reference it expects it to be. If it could change runtime, the anonymous class would essentially operate on the wrong variable.

But since you're trying to re-assign it inside this anynmous class, it can't be final... So what you're trying to do is not possible. I suggest you create a new class keeping track of your `sp`, and then create an `increment()` method on this object.

Comment: mam/ sir.. can you copy my code and run it please ^^.... and give me some solution,,, cause im a begginer ^^ sorry for inconvinience..

Comment: You have already tested the solution. Just don't declare it final.

Comment: but when i dont declare it final,, it says i need to final the int,,,, and when i final the int, it says that the cannot be change,,,

Comment: and i also try this (sp = sp + 1) but its not working ..

Comment: Ok, I see. It's because you're using it in an inner class. What you try to do is essentially not possible. I have updated the answer to reflect this.

Comment: Another solution would be a one-element final array.

Comment: Yes, it would, although it would be somewhat of a "hack". I think it would be more appropriate to create a "score keeping" object.

Comment: tank you sir nilsh ^^

Comment: sir Jan Dvorak,,, can you illustrate what you want to say XD.. i know how to use array but how? :)